# Editable DropdownList in ASP.Net MVC4 razor view [_Duplicate]

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I searched for the solution and went through some posts here. But I didn't come up with the solution. I want to create a editable dropdownlist in asp.net mvc4 for razor view definition. Can anyone please let me know the simplest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to create a custom control or look for some jQuery plugin, as it's not provided as such in MVC.